# How to compute minimum rotation between two bearings

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, geo, bearing

Given two bearings between 0 degree and 360 degrees, A and B, what is the most efficient way to compute the minimum rotation required for A to reach B? The rotation can be clockwise (positive) or anti-clockwise (negative). The minimum rotation should be in whichever direction which gives the smaller absolute degrees.

For example,

minRotation(30,20) yields -10.

minRotation(350,20) yields 30.

How do we formulate the function minRotation(A,B)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 D = B - A
 while D < -180   // use "if" operator when angles are normalized to 0..360 range
    D = D + 360
 while D > 180
    D = D - 360
```

Comment: Is there a reason for choosing 'while' over 'if'?

Comment: Yes, I changed `if` to `while` for  cases like (-300, 750). If your angle ranges are normalized, use `if`

Answer (score 1):

If your language has an equivalent of the C math library remainder() function than

```
D = remainder( B-A, 360.0)
```

Comment: Your formula fails for cases like minRotation(20,350). It should be -30 and not 330.

Comment: @Chong No, my formula gives -30 in that case, From 'man remainder' The remainder() function computes the remainder of dividing x by y.  The return value is x-n*y, where n is the value x / y, rounded to the nearest integer. "Rounded to the nearest integer' is the crucial bit. remainder() is not fmod().

Comment: I see. I have not used C for a long time. I am using JavaScript. Perhaps you can show a link to the function? +1 anyway.